# Kill 'ps aux' output in one line

Tags: linux, macos, ssh, command-line, ps

I have to do the same thing many times a day:

```
ps aux
```

look for process running ssh to one of my servers ...

```
kill -9 <pid>
```

I'm looking to see if I can alias process into one line. The output of ps aux is usually something like this:

```
user   6871   0.0  0.0  4351260      8   ??  Ss    3:28PM   0:05.95 ssh -Nf -L 18881:my-server:18881
user   3018   0.0  0.0  4334292     52   ??  S    12:08PM   0:00.15 /usr/bin/ssh-agent -l
user   9687   0.0  0.0  4294392    928 s002  S+   10:48AM   0:00.00 grep ssh
```

I always want to kill the process with the `my-server` in it.

Does anyone know how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`for pid in $(ps aux | grep "[m]y-server" | awk '{print $2}'); do kill -9 $pid; done`

**ps aux | grep "[m]y-server" | awk '{print $2}'** - this part gives you list of pids processes that include "my-server". And this script will go through this list and kill all this processes.

Answer (score 3):

I use pgrep -- if you're sure you want to kill all the processes that match:

```
$ kill -9 `pgrep my-server`
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use [pkill](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill):

```
sudo pkill my-server
```

Comment: So I simplified the `ps aux` output and in reality there's many more servers being ssh's into in that same line as the `my-server` one. Will this still work?